# Modifying a PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a HttpModule that intercepts requests for PDF documents and I would like to add a date to the PDF and stream back to the client.

My code so far is

```
context.Response.ClearContent();

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(document.Url + "&a=1");
  PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
  // *** Modify PDF here
  stamper.Close();

  context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  context.Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
  context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
  context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
  context.Response.Flush();
  context.Response.End();
}

HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

The code above works fine, but as soon as I try to modify the PDF I get a PDF Reader error 'The file is damaged and cannot be repaired', for example

```
TextField textField = new TextField(stamper.Writer, new Rectangle(0, 1000, 90, 600), name);
textField.Font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE, Font.NORMAL).BaseFont;
textField.FontSize = DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE;
textField.Rotation = 90;
PdfFormField field = textField.GetTextField();

stamper.AddAnnotation(field, page);
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You continue sending stuff after the pdf, add

```
context.Response.End();
```

after:

```
context.Response.Flush();
```

Now you will send only the pdf, instead of the whole page. This sometimes fixes this issue.

You are also reading the buffer twice:

```
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
```

try to add

```
byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
```

and then

```
context.Response.OutputStream.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried that though and still get the same error

Comment: I know you said that it didn't work but I just wanted to make sure that its clear that you **never** use `GetBuffer()` on the `MemoryStream` and **always** use `ToArray()` instead. The former returns extra uninitialized bytes which will be treated as garbage as far as PDF renderers are concerned. The latter only gives you the "used" bytes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx#remarksToggle

Comment: I tried 'ToArray()' in my first example above (without modifying the PDF) and it didn't work, only 'GetBuffer()' worked